Delta hedging of binomial Asian options
The expression of $\Delta$ hedge for a binomial European option is
$$
\Delta_t = \frac{C^u_{t+1}-C^d_{t+1}}{S^u_{t+1}-S^d_{t+1}}
$$
What is the expression of the $\Delta$ hedge for a binomial Asian option?

That is actually the delta one time period ahead. Depending on the granularity of your tree you might want to extend the tree to calculate the delta more accurately.

Basically the same.
But, you will have to define exactly the type of averaging, in particular the frequency.
And the binomial tree will acquire another dimension (the average).
So, in between averaging dates, the formula is exactly the same one (staying on the same level of the 2nd dimension).
Exactly on an averaging date, it will become more sophisticated, but exactly like any other derivative with fixings. You will have a question like
"how will my delta change if the Asian fixed right now at this level"
Which requires a (delta) (i.e. difference) across values of the 2nd dimension.
